# Robots.txt being fetched, then not fetched by GSC

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

For somereason Googlebot cannot see our site. It is an issue with our robots.txt file already but also with individual pages and the sitemap.
The robots file can be fetched when I request them to crawl it. But then after an hour or so it responds with a 404.

Other crawlers I used for testing to give me a 200 status.

Any idea why Google would be able to fetch on and off?

[image: GSC robot.txt log]

Comment: It sounds like there are server issues occurring - a good place to start is checking your web server's error logs, however, you didn't specify which one you're using.

Comment: As Dan said, check 1st your logs. Do you have load balancing enabled? CloudFlare? Other proxies that might interfere? Any IP rate-limiting? ModSecurity? There can be many culprits, you need to track them down.